# Custom delete option button in plugin settings

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, options, settings-api

I would like to add `Delete` button next to my file `Upload` option in my plugin settings.

At this moment I am using Settings API, using form below.

```
<form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
        settings_fields("mw_options");
        do_settings_sections("mw_options");      
        submit_button(); 
    ?>          
</form>
```

It works great, I have about 10 fields in the form, one of them is file upload that adds attachments to a Woocommerce e-mails. Everything works great, but I would like to add `Delete` button next to the `Upload` button in my form, so I can use updated_option or delete_option hook, or something more suited.

I can not figure out, how to do that.

Now I use my own delete_attachment.php and formaction on the button to get the job done, but I would like to do more of this later and I feel there is a better way.

```
function mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1()
{
    ?>
        <input type="file" name="mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1" id="mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1" value="<?php echo get_option('mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1'); ?>" />
        <?php echo get_option("mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1"); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1" formaction="<?php echo plugins_url( 'delete_attachment.php' , __FILE__ );?>" formmethod="post" value="Delete">
    <?php
}
```

How can I create another button within the main option's area that would execute some delete script I have?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to add delete button this way, it also may be used to add any extra submit button.

Create a submit button with name and array attribute:

```
function mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1()
{
    ?>
        <input type="file" name="mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1" id="mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1" value="<?php echo get_option('mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1'); ?>" />
        <?php echo get_option("mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1"); ?>
        <input type="submit" name="submit[delete_attachment_1]" class="button button-primary" value="Delete" />
    <?php
}
```

Register setting with callback function, `mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1_handle` is the name of the function in my case.

```
register_setting("mw_options", "mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1", "mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1_handle");
```

Make the callback function something like this:

```
function mw_options_wc_order_attachement_1_handle($options)
{

    if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $submit_button = $_POST["submit"];

        if (isset($submit_button["delete_attachment_1"])) 
        {
            // delete file
            wp_delete_file('YOUR-FILE-SERVER-PATH');
            return ''; // returns empty option value to settings
        }
    }

 }
```